# flot graph, use legend to turn on/off series

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I want to be able to use the legend of a flot graph to turn on/off the series of my graph. I found the examples on the flot site and have used the [Turning series on/off](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/turning-series.html) and Labelformatter from the API to build what I have right now. I can put checkboxes next the legend elements and add a click event to them and its fires. But that calls the plot function again and resets my checkbox values. I have included the full jquery function, sorry its a bit long.

```
<script id="source">
var jsonPath = "JsonPriceHistory/" + getParameterByName("CardId")



$(function () {
    $.getJSON(jsonPath, function (results) {

        results = [{ "label": "A", "data": [[1290115114240, 0.7000], [1289396258877, 0.7000], [1289394738247, 0.7000], [1288482602563, 0.7000], [1288479321830, 0.7000], [1288464257267, 0.7000], [1288463414413, 0.7000], [1268440264933, 1.0000], [1268434766653, 1.0000], [1268059707567, 1.0000], [1265934534340, 1.0000]] }, { "label": "B", "data": [[1290115102033, 6.0000], [1289395956947, 6.0000], [1289394743117, 6.0000], [1288482613967, 6.0000], [1288479332767, 6.0000], [1288464270420, 6.0000], [1288463427313, 6.0000], [1268440276413, 6.0000], [1268434778203, 6.0000], [1268059732683, 6.0000], [1265934545390, 6.0000]] }, { "label": "C", "data": [[1290115034640, 0.3000], [1289397347113, 0.3000], [1289396593083, 0.3000], [1289395047560, 0.3000], [1288484556080, 0.3000], [1288482794357, 0.3000], [1288465863503, 0.3000], [1288465248087, 0.3000], [1288464674300, 0.3000], [1268470601960, 0.6000], [1268469438957, 0.6000], [1268468281610, 0.6000], [1268440646800, 0.6000], [1265984810360, 0.8000], [1265955747730, 0.8000]] }, { "label": "C", "data": [[1290115031727, 0.1200], [1289397678960, 0.1200], [1289397337040, 0.1200], [1289396577510, 0.1200], [1289395024607, 0.1200], [1288484550417, 0.1200], [1288482780457, 0.1200], [1288465846327, 0.1200], [1288465231287, 0.1200], [1288464658213, 0.1200], [1268470586860, 0.2000], [1268469423697, 0.2000], [1268468266277, 0.2000], [1268440631390, 0.2000], [1265984774793, 0.2000], [1265955732580, 0.2000]] }, { "label": "D", "data": [[1290114958773, 0.0500], [1289397467207, 0.0500], [1289396747243, 0.0500], [1289395166640, 0.0500]] }, { "label": "E", "data": [[1290114933540, 0.6500], [1289397579447, 0.6500], [1289397242333, 0.6500], [1289396486657, 0.6500], [1289395003947, 0.6500], [1288484568590, 0.6500], [1288482784747, 0.6500], [1288465893750, 0.6500], [1288465278320, 0.6500], [1288464705170, 0.6500], [1268470629373, 0.6500], [1268469467810, 0.6500], [1268468309513, 0.6500], [1268440674610, 0.6500], [1265984889857, 0.6500], [1265955775453, 0.6500]] }, { "label": "F", "data": [[1290114885570, 0.1100], [1289396731507, 0.1100], [1289395170397, 0.1100]]}];

        var options = {
            legend: {
                show: true,
                container: $("#overviewLegend"),
                labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
                    var cb = '<input type="checkbox" name="' + label + '" checked="checked" id="id' + label + '"> ' + label;
                    return cb;
                }
            },
            series: {
                points: { show: true },
                lines: { show: true }
            },
            grid: { hoverable: true },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                minTickSize: [1, "day"],
                max: new Date().getTime()
            },
            yaxis: {
                mode: "money",
                min: 0,
                tickDecimals: 2,
                tickFormatter: function (v, axis) { return "$" + v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) }

            }
        };

        var i = 0;
        $.each(results, function (key, val) {
            val.color = i;
            ++i;
        });

        var choiceContainer = $("#overviewLegend");

        function plotAccordingToChoices() {
            var data = [];
            alert('hi');

            choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr("name");
                if (key && results[key])
                    data.push(results[key]);
            });

            $.plot($("#placeholder"), results, options);
            choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);
        }



        var previousPoint = null;
        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
            $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
            $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

            if (item) {
                if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
                    previousPoint = item.datapoint;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + " $" + y);
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                previousPoint = null;
            }
        });

        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 15,
                border: '1px solid #fdd',
                padding: '2px',
                'background-color': '#fee',
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }

        plotAccordingToChoices();
    })



});
```

Comment: Do you think you could link a demo with jsFiddle so I can work directly on your code?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/6FLsM/

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230945/flot-graph-use-legend-to-turn-on-off-series

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a couple of problem with your code:

The data you're using is in the form of an array, while the one presented in the demo is an object. The distinction is important here because you've copied their code, but did not change the code to accommodate this. The lines in question are:

```
if (key && results[key])
    data.push(results[key]);
```

inside the `plotAccordingToChoices()` function. `results[key]` in your case would not work because `key` would need to be a numerical value, but `key` here is a string. The solution is to replace this with a for loop which searches through the array for the correct label:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (results[i].label === key) {
        data.push(results[i]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next, the problem is that you are replotting the same data over and over again, with this line:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), results, options);
```

`results[]` never changes - you should be using `data[]` here instead:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
```

Then, unlike in the demo, you've decided to setup the checkboxes using the `formatlabel` function in the `legend` option when plotting the graph. The problem with this is that when you replot the graph with new data that does not contain all of the results, the checkboxes for the unplotted lines will not show up because flot will not plot the labels of non-existent lines.

This means that you will have to do as the demo does - to create the checkboxes separately. We do this by adding the following lines to the `$.each` loop that is used to fix the colors each line uses:

```
l = val.label;
var li = $('<li />').appendTo(choiceContainer);

$('<input name="' + l + '" id="' + l + '" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />').appendTo(li);
$('<label>', {
    text: l,
    'for': l
}).appendTo(li);
```

This will create a checkbox - label set for each set of data in the `results` array. Finally we move the function for binding `plotAccordingToChoices` to each checkbox outside the function, so that the binding only occurs once, to prevent multiple bindings and the resultant mess:

```
choiceContainer.find("input").change(plotAccordingToChoices);
```

We also change it to use the `change` event instead of `click` because `change` here is more appropriate.

And finally, as a bonus, we loop through the legend table and pull the colors from there to add to the list of checkboxes:

```
$('.legendColorBox > div').each(function(i){
    $(this).clone().prependTo(choiceContainer.find("li").eq(i));
});
```

We also need a little CSS for this to work:

```
#overviewLegend li > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

**See the final working code live here: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/6FLsM/2/**

Comment: thank you very for your help, this is my first real project using jquery or flot. I do mostly asp.net/c# work.

Comment: how to get check boxes inside the canvas.(same column with the legend)

Comment: is it possible to use the colored boxes instead of adding tick boxes