# flot: zoom, hover and series selection in the same plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to plot 3 different series on the same plot.  I want to do the following in the plot:

- allow the user to select which series are plotted ("[Turning series on/off](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/turning-series.html)" example on the flot website),
- allow the user to zoom in and zoom out ("[Rectangular selection with zooming](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/selection.html)" example),
- show the values of the curves when the user hovers the mouse ("[Tracking curves](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/tracking.html)" example).

I have been trying to make it work for a long time now, and I can't get everything to work.  [My current attempt](http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/flot_test/data/plot_displacement.html) fails to properly turn series on/off.  As soon as I check a box, the graph becomes blank.  The javascript file which defines all the plotting functions etc., is [`plot_displacement.js`](http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/flot_test/data/plot_displacement.js).

The relevant part of the code is:

```
var choice_container = jQuery("#choices");
choice_container.find("input").change(do_plot);
```

The HTML is:

```
<p id="choices">Show:</p> 
<div id="plotdiv" style="width:600px;height:300px;position:static;"></div>
```

I am using `change` and not `click` because of [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230945/flot-graph-use-legend-to-turn-on-off-series).  If I use `click`, then selecting/unselecting the checkboxes doesn't seem to have any effect.

I am sure I am overlooking something simple, but I can't figure out what.  I would love to be able to do all the 3 things that I am trying to do in flot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply that `do_plot` is being called from your change event with xmin being a jQuery Event object.  You expect it to be undefined and then set to 0, but instead you're passing xmin: jQuery.Event to flot, which doesn't know what to do with it.

**Edit**: Since someone asked, the actual code you might want to put in there, when checking if xmin is undefined, additionally check whether it is an object (`jQuery.Event` has a typeof `object`):

```
    if (typeof(xmin) == 'undefined' || typeof(xmin) == 'object') xmin = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Click does work for me.

I use the code from the Flot example:

```
$("#checkboxes").find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);
```

Clicking the checkboxes calls:

```
function plotAccordingToChoices() {
    var data = [];

    $("#checkboxes").find("input:checked").each(function () {
        var key = $(this).attr("name");
        if (key && datasets[key])
            data.push(datasets[key]);
    });

    if (data.length > 0){
        plot = $.plot($("#chart1"), data, options);
    }
}
```

datasets is a global array keyed by the set name and was created at initialization.