# Persisting flot legend label checkbox on un-check

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I have a scenario where I want to toggle series based on checkbox selection. I have added the checkbox to the legend using **labelFormatting** in legend option like:

```
     var otherOptions = {
                           legend: {
                                     container: legend,
                                     labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
                                        var cb = '<input type="checkbox" name="' + label + '" checked="checked" id="id' + label + '"> ' + label;
                                        return cb;
                                     }
                            },
                         };
```

And I have added the click event for the legend so that I can manipulate the series based on checked items. It all works fine except when I uncheck a label in legend, on re-draw it removes that series line from the legend as well. So for ex., below is the before and after image:

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Notice that in after image "USA" checkbox is missing.
Is there any way I can still show the unchecked "USA" checkbox in legend?

I looked at the suggestion here: [flot graph, use legend to turn on/off series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230945/flot-graph-use-legend-to-turn-on-off-series)

But the only problem is that I don't want to have legend AND checkbox legend separate. The question on the given link was answered 1+ year ago so I thought I am gonna take a chance and ask the question again in case someone knows a way to do this.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of removing the series all together if the checkbox is unchecked, add it with empty data.

Something like this:

```
function plotByChoice(doAll)
{
  $('#legend .legendCB').each(
   function(){
     if (this.checked)
     {         
       data.push(datasets[someLabel]);
     }
     else
     {
       data.push({label: someLabel, data: []})
     }        
   }
 );

 // plot call etc...
}
```

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/GVt9V/1/).

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you so much Mark!

Answer (score 1):

#### For anyone looking for a clean solution AND for Chart.js v3 :

This is unfortunately not possible for Chart.js v3 as legends are generated with text (no HTML can be appended to the legend itself, unfortunately).

We have to use `generateLabels` function to render the legend labels.

I suggest using the `pointStyle` option to render an image (checkbox, actually), instead of a rectangle by default, so we can rerender automatically everytime the user checks or not the legend (it's dynamic, ofc, and we don't have to do something complicated programmatically).

So, first, generate the 2 images, corresponding to the checkboxes (I'm using FontAwesome icons that I've generated in PNG from SVG files) :

```
let checkboxYes = new Image(14, 14);
checkboxYes.src = '/static/img/check_yes.png';
let checkboxNo = new Image(14, 14);
checkboxNo.src = '/static/img/check_no.png';
```

Then, we can use it in the Chart.js options:

```
legend: {
    labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
            labels = Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
            for (var key in labels) {
                labels[key].pointStyle = labels[key].hidden ? checkboxNo : checkboxYes
            }
            return labels;
          }
    }
},
```

#### Explanations

- I'm setting `usePointStyle` to **true** so that I can customize the point style
  later
- `Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart)` kind of pre generate the labels for me (and store it into labels), so it's like a function override!
- Then for each label, I'm changing its `pointStyle` to the checkbox image **depending on the `hidden` parameter** (if the user checked the box)
- Finally, return the labels

It's perhaps not the best solution, but works amazingly well for me:

[Click here to see the animated result in GIF :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOW8I.gif)

Answer (score 0):

i did it in the same manner but when i click on legends all of the legends get disappear , even i updated the onclick function as well it is not working for me

labels: {
usePointStyle: true,

```
          // eslint-disable-next-line object-shorthand
          generateLabels: (chart) => {
            let labels = Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
        
            labels = labels.map((label) => ({
              ...label,
              pointStyle: label.hidden ? checkboxNo : checkboxYes,
              font: {
                size: 14,
                family: 'Montserrat',
                weight: 600,
              },
              color: label.hidden ? '#999' : '#323C46',
              margin: {
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
              },
              // Handle click event to toggle visibility of the clicked legend item
              onClick: (e, legendItem, legend) => {
                console.log(legendItem)
                const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
                const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(index);
                meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !chart.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
                chart.update();
              },
            }));
        
            return labels;
          },
        },
```

and i am not able apply any style as well.